# How to put callback from Java method into text in React Native

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native

In my java, I have a method:

```
@ReactMethod
public void testMethod(Callback callback) {
  String thisString = "Foo bar";
  callback.invoke(thisString);
}
```

I would like to display thisString in my application as text. I am using the following call to get the callback:

`NativeModules.FirstTest.testMethod((msg) => window.alert(msg))`

This displays an alert containing thisString just fine, but I cannot get it to put thisString as text in the description field of my ListView. I have tried `=> msg` and every native JS function to print this that I can think of.

How do I display the callback received from Java as text?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the name inside the callback function.

```
NativeModules.FirstTest.testMethod((msg) => listView.setText(msg))
```

Comment: listView gives me "Can't find variable listView"

I also tried ListView and got "undefined is not a function (evaluating '_ReactNative.ListView.setText(msg)'

I know that ListView is imported (as it is showing in my emulator and it's imported at the top of my file). Is there something I'm missing?